# How to add multiple classes to classlist.contains in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find a solution that allows me to update the following code to include additional classes. E.g. in addition to .section--bg1, I'd like to include .section--bg2. and .section--bg3.

**How can I include the red coloured background section (.section--bg2) in the JavaScript?**

I've tried "`el.classList.contains('section--bg1', 'section--bg2');`" but that is not working. What am I missing?

```
// active section
if ( (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) && (sectionBottom > replaceItemTop)) {
  // check if current section has bg
  currentSection = el.classList.contains('section--bg1');

  // switch class depending on background image
  if ( currentSection ) { 
    replaceContainer[0].classList.remove('js-replace--reverse');
  } else {
    replaceContainer[0].classList.add('js-replace--reverse')
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**In case this helps someone. This is what worked for me:**

```
// active section
    if ( (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) && (sectionBottom > replaceItemTop)) {
      // check if current section has bg
      currentSection = el.classList.contains('section--bg1') || el.classList.contains('section--bg2') || el.classList.contains('section--bg3');
```

Comment: The [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method only accepts a single `token`.

Comment: The answer involving `.matches()` is the easiest thing to do. You'd want `.matches(".section--bg1, .section--bg2")`, which will be true when the element has either class (or both of them).

Answer (score 1):

Use `matches()` to check whether an element contains ANY of classes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

```js
console.log($div.matches('.class1,.class2'));
console.log($div2.matches('.class1,.class2'));
```

```html
<div id="$div" class="class1"></div>
<div id="$div2" class="class2"></div>
```

Applying to your code, use also `classList.toggle()` to make the code shorter:

```
// active section
if ( (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) && (sectionBottom > replaceItemTop)) {

  // switch class depending on background image
  replaceContainer[0].classList.toggle('js-replace--reverse', !el.matches('.section--bg1,.section--bg2,.section--bg3'));
```

Comment: Or `'.class1, .class2'` if what is wanted is *either* "class1" or "class2".

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how to implement that, Any chance you could update the fiddle or provide the full script for context?

Comment: @DavidMartins if this solves your problem don't forget to accept and upvote the answer, thanks

Comment: Still trying to make it work... Yes! I'll definitely do that as soon as I can get this fixed.

Comment: @DavidMartins seems the problem isn't related to the question and answer.

Comment: OK. I'm not doubting you have the right approach, but if you look at the fiddle, it's just not working. Can you tell me why? https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/r0em4svn/3/

Answer (score 0):

To include multiple classes in the el.classList.contains() check, you should use  separate classList.contains() calls for each class you want to check. Here's how you can modify your code to include both .section--bg1 and .section--bg2:

```js
// active section
if (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom && sectionBottom > replaceItemTop) {
  // check if current section has bg1 or bg2
  const hasBg1 = el.classList.contains('section--bg1');
  const hasBg2 = el.classList.contains('section--bg2');
  const hasBg3 = el.classList.contains('section--bg3');

  // switch class depending on background image
  if (hasBg1 || hasBg2 || hasBg3) {
    replaceContainer[0].classList.remove('js-replace--reverse');
  } else {
    replaceContainer[0].classList.add('js-replace--reverse');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Your suggestion works to some extent, but the effect is gone. Here is a fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/rzan2eus/1/

Answer (score 0):

The [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method only accepts a single `token`.

You need to call the method twice with each different class and AND the conditions:

```js
if (
  el.classList.contains('section--bg1') &&
  el.classList.contains('section--bg2')
) {
  // ...
}
```

If you want to be fancy, you can write a convenience function:

```js
const containsAll = (arr, ...tokens) =>
  tokens.every(token => arr.contains(token));

const containsOne = (arr, ...tokens) =>
  tokens.some(token => arr.contains(token));

const foo = document.querySelector('#foo');

console.log(containsAll(foo.classList, 'bar', 'baz'));

console.log(containsOne(foo.classList, 'beep', 'boop', 'bar'));
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="bar baz"></div>
```